# Консольное меню

Tags: pascal

Приветствую, программисты. Есть вопрос, поступило задание: максимально просто объеденить в консольном приложении несколько лабораторных работ. Как это лучше всего реализовать? Вид идеи такой. Человек пишет номер задания и оно выполняется. Если можно, то с ссылкой на примерчик.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Легче всего:

```
var
num: integer;
begin
write("Введите номер задания: ");
readln(num);
if num=156 then begin
{идет код задания 156}
end;
if num=223 then begin
{идет код задания 223}
end;
if num=718 then begin
{идет код задания 718}
end;
if num<>156 AND num<>223 AND num<>718 then begin
writeln("Такого задания нет.");
readln();
end;
end.
```

Более сложный способ - через процедуры и функции. =)

**UPD**:
Case не сильно спасет=)

```
case  num  of
      '156' : begin {идет код задания 156} end;
      '223' : begin {идет код задания 223} end;
      '718' : begin {идет код задания 718} end;
else    begin
                  writeln("Такого задания нет.");
                  readln();
                  end;
end;
```

Comment: да вот в том то и беда, что для каждого задание своя специфика, и придется сильно нагромождать . я где-то видел реализацию через case но так и не могу найти где. Что находится - либо сложно либо не подходит, а надо элементарно-оптимальное решение)

Comment: Добавил. В вашем случае, Case не сильно упростит ситуацию...

Comment: Словечко otherwise замените на else (слова otherwise в Паскале нет).

Comment: Эм... с чем-то перепутал, разве? Ладно, спасибо.